# SimpleDateFormatter not working correctly

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have the following code snippet.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            String calString = "Sat Sep 27 00:00:00 EDT 2014";
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY");
            System.out.println("calString " + calString);

            Date date = formatter.parse(calString);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            System.out.println("month " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            System.out.println("day " + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
            System.out.println("format date" + df.format(date));
            return df.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Expected output should be `20140927`

but I'm getting this instead.

```
calString Sat Sep 27 00:00:00 EDT 2014
month 0
day 3
format date 20140103
```

Anybody know why the day and month are off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Y` represents week year. `y` is used to match the year

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`. That means "week year", to be used in conjunction with "week of year". Just change `YYYY` to `yyyy` in both of your `SimpleDateFormat` constructors and you'll get output of:

```
calString Sat Sep 27 00:00:00 EDT 2014
month 8
day 27
format date20140927
```

Note that month is 8 rather than 9 because months in `java.util.Calendar` are 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

A little more healthy solution

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
                                                                ,Locale.ENGLISH);
```